# I am getting Keyerror while using set default

Tags: python, setdefault

While execting this, I got the following error.

"FAIL : KeyError: 'first_session'

Error is from the 3rd line, which uses the session_name while calling the defenition _get_xml_func.
Need a help to idenity the issue.

```py
def func_get (index=None, *elements,**params):  
    session_name = params.setdefault('session_name', "first_session")
    xml = _get_xml_func(index, *elements, session_name=session_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

The 1st parameter of `setdefault()` is the key name, the second - the value to set. The exception is for missing "first_session", which you have passed in as a value, not a key.